# Center UITextField in UIAlertController

Tags: ios, swift

When I use storyboard element(text view, label), everything is working and I have text field in the middle of alert controller. But when I want to make it by code (text field except storyboard), it's not working. Here is code.

```
func addAlert(){
        // create the alert
        let title = "This is the title"
        let message = "This is the message"
        var alert = UIAlertController(title: title, message: message, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert);
        alert.modalInPopover = true;

        // add an action button
        let nextAction: UIAlertAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Action", style: .Default){action->Void in
            // do something
        }
        alert.addAction(nextAction)

        // now create our custom view - we are using a container view which can contain other views
        let containerViewWidth = 250
        let containerViewHeight = 120
        var containerFrame = CGRectMake(10, 70, CGFloat(containerViewWidth), CGFloat(containerViewHeight));
        var containerView: UIView = UIView(frame: containerFrame);

        alert.view.addSubview(containerView)

        var newProjectTextField = UITextField(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 31))
        newProjectTextField.center = CGPointMake(160, 284)
        newProjectTextField.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Center
        newProjectTextField.placeholder = "New project's name"

        alert.view.addSubview(newProjectTextField)

        // now add some constraints to make sure that the alert resizes itself
        var cons:NSLayoutConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: alert.view, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Height, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.GreaterThanOrEqual, toItem: containerView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Height, multiplier: 1.00, constant: 130)
        alert.view.addConstraint(cons)

        var cons2:NSLayoutConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: alert.view, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Width, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.GreaterThanOrEqual, toItem: containerView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Width, multiplier: 1.00, constant: 20)
        alert.view.addConstraint(cons2)

        var centerXConstraint:NSLayoutConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: newProjectTextField, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.CenterX, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: alert.view, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.CenterX, multiplier: 1.00, constant: 0.0)
        alert.view.addConstraint(centerXConstraint)

        var centerYConstraint:NSLayoutConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: newProjectTextField, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.CenterY, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: alert.view, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.CenterY, multiplier: 1.00, constant: 0.0)
        alert.view.addConstraint(centerYConstraint)

        // present with our view controller
        presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

[image: uitextfield]

Comment: Are you receiving any constraint warnings/errors in the log? And what is the current result (that you are unsatisfied with)?

Comment: What is the result of the code? What do you see on screen. Are there any constraint warnings/errors?

Comment: @Firo I have so many constraints warnings that I can't even count :-D But not about this problem. I have added screenshot of what it looks like right now. The Text Field is centered, but it expand Y coordinates of alert.

Comment: @abdullah As I wrote, no errors, but it expanded in the Y coordinates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
newProjectTextField.center = CGPointMake(250,120)
```

That will center without expanding the y-axis. Not sure if that's exactly what you are looking for though.

Comment: Yes, I am just an idi.. It was that simple. Thank you ;)